# React Native - cannot connect to Metro on API 31/32 (Android 12) either on emulator or real device, even with adb reverse

Tags: android, typescript, react-native

Cleartext is enabled in the manifest.
I have done `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` command.
The same app readily works on an API 28 emulator.

I get the message `Could not connect to development server.`

Is there another reason why Android 12 might cause problems with this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you running the emulator at the same time as the device? Try running `adb reverse -s <device_name> tcp:8081 tcp:8081`, you can get the device name from adb devices

Answer (score -1):

The issue was the need to add `localhost` to `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <base-config>
    <trust-anchors>
      <!-- Trust preinstalled CAs -->
      <certificates src="system" />
      <!-- Additionally trust user added CAs -->
      <certificates src="user" />
    </trust-anchors>
  </base-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: This does not work for us @karatekid430